# Elasticsearch sort script can only access keyword field as String

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-painless

This is my query,Elasticsearch version is 7.10.0

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "sort": {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['my_field'].value - params.paramVal",
          "params": {
            "paramVal": 1
          }
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    "profile": false
  }
```

which my_field is an Integer keyword field.But this query result in an error

```
  "reason": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "doc['my_field'].value - params.paramVal",
      "                              ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "doc['my_field'].value - params.paramVal",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
      "offset": 33,
      "start": 0,
      "end": 49
    },
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "class_cast_exception",
      "reason": "class_cast_exception: Cannot apply [-] operation to types [java.lang.String] and [java.lang.Integer]."
    }
  }
```

Now I'm using Integer.parseInt(doc['my_field'].value) to workaround.Any idea to use the int field value directly?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `my_field` is an "Integer keyword field", I assume that it is stored as a string. If that's the case, then `doc['my_field'].value` returns a string and Painless won't allow you to subtract an integer from a string. You need to parse that string, like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(doc['my_field'].value) - params.paramVal
```

If `my_field` is supposed to contain an integer value you should probably store it as an `integer` type instead of keyword, especially if you need to run `range` queries on that field.

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want or can't reindex and want to still keep your current index, another thing you can do is to add an `integer` sub-field and update your index in place. It goes like this:

```
# First add an integer sub-field to your mapping
PUT index/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "my_field": {
         "type": "keyword",
         "fields": {
            "numeric": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

# then update your index in-place
POST index/_update_by_query
```

When the update is done, the new `my_field.numeric` field will have been populated using the existing data in the keyword field and you can use it in your Painless script like this:

```
doc['my_field.numeric'].value - params.paramVal
```

Comment: so,the keyword is a string and there is no way to change that?but why in the search hit _source it shows as an int?like this
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "11",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "my_field": 6,
        }

Comment: If `my_field` is declared as `keyword` in your mapping and you send an `integer` in your source document, it's still going to be a keyword. You just need to create a new index with a correct mapping to use `integer` instead of `keyword` and reindex your data into the new index.

Comment: Is there any way to let the keyword field store the data as its real type?

Comment: See my updated answer